# UIButtonを修飾する方法

Tags: xcode

UIButtonをデザイン修飾したいのですが、その方法に

1. Storyboardsでボタンを配置
2. コードから編集

というふうにしています。

しかし、コード側で

```
import UIKit

class ButtonTest: UIViewController {

    //ボタンを登録
    @IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //背景を真っ赤にする
        btn1.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
}
```

のように記述しても何も変化がありません........

そもそもこのような修飾方法はあまりいいものではないのでしょうか？
調べてみてもボタンそのものをコード側で生成して追加するものか、完全にXcodeのIDE側で設定してしまう側のどちらかしか見つからなくて........

このような方法でもうまくいく方法があれば是非とも教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ボタンに画像が設定されてないのであれば`imageView`プロパティのサイズはゼロなので、それに背景色を設定しても外観に影響はありません。

```
btn1.backgroundColor = .redColor()
```

上記のように、直接ボタンの`backgroundColor`プロパティに色を設定すると良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: kishikawa katsumiさん
毎度ありがとうございます！

imageViewは画像だったのですね。
ありがとうございます！

Comment: 過去の質問もなのですが、問題が解決したなら、その回答を承認して解決済にしていただけますか？そうしないといつまでも質問が未解決のまま残ってしまい、定期的に新着に上がってきてしまいます。